Cauchy's Integral Theorem for boundary of compact set

Assume $\gamma$ is a simple closed rectifiable curve on the complex plane $\mathbb C$ and $\Omega$ is the origin inside $\gamma$, $D=\overline\Omega$. Let $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb C$ be a complex function which is continous on $\partial D$ and holomorphism in $\Omega$. Prove that
$$
\int_{\gamma}f(z)\mathrm dz=0
$$

Difficulties I met: It seems like ordinary Cauchy's Integral Theorem, However, $\gamma$ is  the boundary of the origin, we cannot find a bigger origin that contain D; Also, we donot know the (piecewise) smoothness of $\gamma$, so we cannot use Green's Theorem.
Efforts I made: I Hope to find a way to approach $\gamma$ by some broken lines inside $\Omega$ and then use Goursat's Theorem to finish my proof.

The question is too vague. 'Inside $\gamma$' is technically very complicated and you will have to study Jordan Curve Theorem before trying to answer this question.
